# How to start Chrome Browser through Chromedriver and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting error issues all of a sudden with selenium and the chromedriver. I haven't changed a single thing yet I am met with these error messages. The script literally worked hours ago and now without any tweaks its not working.

```
 traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 20, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\Scripts\email.py", line 12, in <module>
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

Here is my corresponding code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
#caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r'load-extension=C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\facebookpixelhelper')
#options.add_argument('start-fullscreen')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = caps, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('http://www.doelabs.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Even more strange is that when open new terminal, load python, and type from selenium import webdriver, i dont get any errors. But, when I navigate to the folder where the script lives, and load python and type from selenium import webdriver, i get the error message that shows up above. I hope this can give some insight into my current predicament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few words about the solution :

- **email** is a *reserved word* / *keyword* in **Python Language**, avoid using the word **email** within user defined filename/methods/classes.
- `pageLoadStrategy` as **`eager`** is yet to be implemented in *ChromeDriver*, use either **`none`** or **`normal`** instead as per your requirement.
- To maximize the *Chrome Browser Window* instead of `maximize_window()` use the argument **start-maximized** through **`ChromeOptions()`**
- To load an extension use **ChromeOptions** as follows :

  ```
  options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
  ```

Here are the four methods to initialize **Chrome Browser** through **ChromeDriver** :

- *Vanila Method* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.doelabs.com/')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Arguments as *ChromeOptions* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.addExtensions(new File("C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\facebookpixelhelper.crx"));
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.doelabs.com/')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Capabilities as *DesiredCapabilities* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME.copy()
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=caps)
  driver.get('http://www.doelabs.com/')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Arguments as *ChromeOptions* and Capabilities as *DesiredCapabilities* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME.copy()
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.addExtensions(new File("C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\facebookpixelhelper.crx"));
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=caps)
  driver.get('http://www.doelabs.com/')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough response! The filename being email.py was definitely the problem in my case. It was also affecting other scripts I had wrote in the past so I was super confused. Thanks for tweaking the other parts of my script!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change

```
executable_path=r'C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\chromedriver',
```

to

```
executable_path=r'C:\Users\Doe Labs\Desktop\Austin\sales_prospecting\chromedriver.exe',
```

You seem to have missed .exe, the extension of the executable file.